# Asteroid Theory of Dinosaur Extinction

Tags: geophysics, climate-science, asteroids

Have proponents of the Chicxulub dinosaur extinction theory wildly exaggerated the effect of asteroid impact in order to validate their theory? For example,the world-wide forest fire claim doesn't stand up to examination. Fossil tree leaves contemporary with the impact & within about 2,000 miles of it have been discovered unburned,& it is impossible to start a wildfire in really damp rainforest. Also,the Deccan Traps super-volcano is likely to have made a much greater contribution to climate change. Creatures far more fragile than dinosaurs which didn't live in burrows or caves nevertheless survived the impact.

Comment: But those small (mammal) survivors needed much less food per day...

Comment: True,but I don't see what bearing this has on the question In any case,small animals can consume as much food as large ones if they have the numbers,for example locusts & quelea. Some mammals survived in burrows & caves,others survived in the open,but I was thinking more in terms of birds & insects etc. Some large animals survived too,crocodiles & tortoises for instance.

Comment: You consider crocodiles large? Compared to dinosaurs that were 50 or more tons?

Comment: The majority of dinosaurs weighed far less than 50 tons. Modern crocodiles can weigh well over a ton,& there may well have been larger ones in those days.

Comment: This seems less like an actual question and more like a series of assertions. In any case, what makes you think that the global firestorm hypothesis and the Chixculub asteroid impact are one and the same thing? Evidence against the global firestorm hypothesis isn't necessarily evidence against the asteroid impact (also, most of your assertions aren't examples of evidence against the global firestorm hypothesis anyway; for example, leaves can be buried many years before the impact and still be called "contemporary").

Comment: The question is in the first sentence. The other sentences may be assertons,but they point out a number of facts that you need to know in order to answer the question sensibly without repeating the inaccurate propaganda of the catastrophists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: There was a tag of ASTRONOMY offered to me,so I used it. If astronomy isn't physics,why was I offered an astronomy label? I could have sworn I have seen astronomy questions here before.

Comment: No, your question is not about physics. It is about, perhaps, the sociology of science. Your question is whether we believe that somebody exaggerated some claims. That is not physics.

Comment: I don't dispute that there was a mass extinction 66m years ago,but if forests survived (& there is much evidence that they did) the world-wide forest fire is an exaggeration. My statement on damp rainforests is from personal experience: I spent many years in the rainforests of Malaysia. Dayaks regularly burn patches of rainforest to make their ladangs,but to do that they must first cut them & dry them in the sun. Only then can they be burned. No precautions are taken to see that the surrounding rainforest doesn't catch fire,because it can't. Far less could hot embers from 10,000m away do it.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby It seems like you yourself hold both an exaggerated view of the global firestorm hypothesis (i.e. that it killed literally every plant) and also underestimate it at the same time (by saying that heating the entire upper atmosphere to a temperature of 800-1100 K for several hours wouldn't be enough to set things on fire). You can't say that the impact is simultaneously too strong and too weak to be plausible, that's not really how logic works.

Comment: You're putting words into my mouth,& that is a very naughty thing to do. It was never my case that there were no forest fires,but the evidence suggests that there were few or none more than 2,000m away  I don't believe for a moment that the entire upper atmosphere was heated to 1,000 K for several hours throughout the world,& although I have studied this subject for many years I've never seen any evidence for it. Putting words into people's mouths & quoting "facts" for which there is no evidence is not an ethical way to win an argument. How would birds have survived in the scenario you paint?

Comment: @MichaelWalsby As I already explained, the fact that we can find leaves close to the impact crater which were buried within a few thousand years of the event isn't evidence against the presence of forest fires. The leaves could have been buried centuries before the event (or during the ensuing tsunami). The 1,000-K figure comes from https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Don_Latham/publication/11810863_Ignition_of_Global_Wildfires_at_the_Cretaceous-Tertiary_Boundary/links/00b7d528bb52bca73a000000/Ignition-of-Global-Wildfires-at-the-Cretaceous-Tertiary-Boundary.pdf.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby Once again, I'd like to emphasize that the global firestorm hypothesis is **separate** from the idea that the impact was largely responsible for the mass extinction. I never said that the global firestorm hypothesis was well-supported enough to be consensus; I was simply describing what it said, to make sure we're talking about the same idea. More recent research suggests that the global infrared pulse didn't last long enough to start fires on its own, but it dried out most plants, making them more flammable (https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/sepm/jgs/article/172/2/175/144747).

Comment: @MichaelWalsby If you had actually read my answer and the papers cited within it, you would know that the question of how birds survived is answered by this study: http://uahost.uantwerpen.be/funmorph/raoul/macroevolutie/robertson2004.pdf

Comment: Perhaps my answers to other comments might supply some of the evidence you are asking for,but my time for answering correspondents is limited.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question:

> Have proponents of the Chicxulub dinosaur extinction theory wildly exaggerated the effect of asteroid impact in order to validate their theory?

The answer is "probably not", given that the research has gradually become more and more certain about the impact's role in the extinction. If they really were exaggerating the effect, you would expect the field to eventually become less and less certain of the impact's importance over time. Roughly 20 years after the initial theory was put forward, an international team of 41 experts from various institutions and subfields evaluated the evidence gathered in those two decades to assess whether Deccan volcanism or the Chixculub impact was the trigger for the Cretaceous-Paleogene extinction event (Schulte et al, 2010, https://science.sciencemag.org/content/327/5970/1214). They concluded that the Chixculub impact was the trigger of the extinction event.

Now, to address your assertions:

> For example,the world-wide forest fire claim doesn't stand up to examination. Fossil tree leaves contemporary with the impact & within about 2,000 miles of it have been discovered unburned,& it is impossible to start a wildfire in really damp rainforest.

There are several things that are problematic here:

- The idea that the asteroid caused a "world-wide forest fire" is a **separate** idea from the asteroid causing the mass extinction event. Evidence against the firestorm is not evidence against the asteroid causing the mass extinction. The asteroid impact can cause a mass extinction without starting a global firestorm.
- In paleontology, "contemporary" has a rather broad definition. Due to uncertainties in dating methods, the error bars on the ages of fossils are not uncommonly thousands of years wide. The leaves that are considered "contemporary" with the impact could have been buried centuries earlier - or centuries later (see the aforementioned paper for examples of this).
- The asteroid impact also caused a tsunami that could quite easily bury a large amount of foliage close to the impact site.
- It is not, in fact, impossible to start a wildfire in a damp rainforest. See, for example, this source explaining that they happen: https://rainforestpartnership.org/amazon-wildfires/. In particular, the 1997-1998 El Niño event was accompanied by fires in 13,200 square miles of Brazilian forests and rainforests.

> Also,the Deccan Traps super-volcano is likely to have made a much greater contribution to climate change.

The Deccan Traps supervolcano is addressed in the paper above (Schulte et al). They find insufficient evidence that it was more important than the Chixculub impact for mass extinction. Its relevance to climate change is, again, a separate idea that doesn't really have anything to do with the rest of what you say, since climate change and mass extinctions, while related, are not the same thing.

> Creatures far more fragile than dinosaurs which didn't live in burrows or caves nevertheless survived the impact.

In 2004, a team consisting of a geophysicist, an atmospheric physicist, an environmental scientist, an ornithologist, and a zoologist published an article in the Journal of the Geological Society of America which addresses how certain species may have survived the impact event (http://uahost.uantwerpen.be/funmorph/raoul/macroevolutie/robertson2004.pdf). Their survival is therefore still consistent with the asteroid impact causing a mass extinction.

Comment: I have never denied that the asteroid impact played a part in dinosaur extinction. All I am saying is that there is evidence to suggest that  that catastrophists have exaggerated its effect in order to validate their claim that it was the sole cause.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby And you have not provided this evidence, I don't find it in my own searches, and the assertions you provided are not evidence of it, as I've explained above. Again, it seems like you came here to make a statement, not ask a question.